# Readline-style bracket highlighting in Zsh

Tags: zsh, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes I write a long command in Zsh, or rather, a Zsh command ending with a long string literal containing code for another language like R or Perl, and I lose track of my parentheses, square brackets, or braces. The Readline variable `blink-matching-paren` briefly flashes the corresponding opening bracket when you type a close bracket. How can I get something like that for Zsh? Even better would be an equivalent of Emacs's `show-paren-mode`, which highlights the corresponding matching bracket whenever the text cursor is on a bracket.

The `brackets` highlighter from `zsh-syntax-highlighting` is something in this direction, but it doesn't function in quoted constructs, which is where I really need it (although, confusingly, it still highlights brackets if they're backslash-escaped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `zsh` has an equivalent builtin mechanism, but you should be able to do it with a custom widget like:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
showmatch() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o rematchpcre
  local -A pair=(
    ']' '['
    ')' '('
    '}' '{'
  )
  local MBEGIN

  zle .self-insert
  if [[ $LBUFFER =~ "(\\$pair[$KEYS](?:[^$KEYS$pair[$KEYS]]++|(?1))*\\$KEYS)\$" ]]; then
    local oldCURSOR=$CURSOR
    CURSOR=$MBEGIN-1
    zle -R
    zselect -t 50 -r 0 < /dev/tty
    CURSOR=$oldCURSOR
  fi
}
zle -N showmatch
bindkey ']' showmatch
bindkey ')' showmatch
bindkey '}' showmatch
```

You could also temporarily highlight the region between the matching brackets by replacing the inside of `if`/`fi` with something like:

```
    local oldCURSOR=$CURSOR
    region_highlight+=("$((MBEGIN-1)) $CURSOR bg=yellow,fg=black,bold")
    CURSOR=$MBEGIN-1
    zle -R
    zselect -t 50 -r 0 < /dev/tty
    CURSOR=$oldCURSOR
    region_highlight[-1]=()
```

(here highlighting in black on yellow).

You could also combine that with some `show-paren-mode`-like highlighting of matched brackets when the cursor hits one end with something like:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
SHOWMATCH_GR=fg=black,bg=yellow,bold

showmatch() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o rematchpcre
  local -A pair=(
    ']' '['
    ')' '('
    '}' '{'
  )
  local MBEGIN

  zle .self-insert
  if [[ $LBUFFER =~ "(\\$pair[$KEYS](?:[^$KEYS$pair[$KEYS]]++|(?1))*\\$KEYS)\$" ]]; then
    local oldCURSOR=$CURSOR
    local -a old_region_highlight=($region_highlight)
    region_highlight+=("$((MBEGIN-1)) $CURSOR $SHOWMATCH_GR")
    CURSOR=$MBEGIN-1
    zle -R
    zselect -t 50 -r 0 < /dev/tty
    CURSOR=$oldCURSOR
    region_highlight=($old_region_highlight)
  fi
}
zle -N showmatch
bindkey ']' showmatch
bindkey ')' showmatch
bindkey '}' showmatch

zle-line-pre-redraw() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o rematchpcre
  region_highlight=(${region_highlight:#* $SHOWMATCH_GR})
  local a=$BUFFER[CURSOR+1] b c MBEGIN o=0
  local -A pair=(
    ']' '['
    ')' '('
    '}' '{'
  )
  [[ -n "$RBUFFER" ]] &&
  case $a in
    ([[\({])
      b=${(k)pair[(re)$a]}
      [[ $RBUFFER =~ "^(\\$a(?:[^$b$a]++|(?1))*\\$b)" ]] && o=$CURSOR;;
    ([]\)}])
      b=$pair[$a]
      [[ $LBUFFER$a =~ "(\\$b(?:[^$a$b]++|(?1))*\\$a)\$" ]];;
    (*) return;;
  esac &&
    region_highlight+=("$((o+MBEGIN-1)) $((o+MEND)) $SHOWMATCH_GR")
}
zle -N zle-line-pre-redraw
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Kodiologist, see edit for a `show-paren-mode`-like enhancement.